# WooCommerce API List all products with a specific attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, get, woocommerce-rest-api

Using the WooCommerce API I want to send an HTTP GET request to download all products with a specific attribute.

The [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction) says the URL to do this with is this:

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products
```

And I can add parameters to the URL in order to filter the products.

I have successfully added filters for page and page count:

```
wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100&page=10
```

I have also managed to get only available products with this parameter:

```
wp-json/wc/v3/products?&stock_status=instock
```

However, I cannot manage to add a filter for the attributes. I have tried the following ways to write the URL and non of them work

```
wp-json/wc/v3/products/?attribute=1
wp-json/wc/v3/products/?
wp-json/wc/v3/products/?attribute_pa_емаг=Да
wp-json/wc/v3/products/?filter[pa_емаг]=10
```

What would be the correct way to write the URL?

(Note: The attribute is pa_емаг and its value is Да)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct call would be:

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products?attribute={attribute-taxonomy}&attribute_term={term-id/tag_ID}
```

Where **attribute-taxonomy** would be full slug in your case "pa_емаг", and **term-id/tag_ID** the id of "Да".

Comment: How do I find the id of "Да" do you have any idea?

Comment: @Denis Either going to the admin attribute page, you can see the id in the link, calling it programmatically, or calling it from [REST API](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-product-attributes). If the answer is correct please upvote or set it as answered.