# List all the products with attribute using WooCommerce REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to send an HTTP GET request to get all the products with a specific attribute using WooCommerce REST API. I am following [this](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#list-all-products) WooCommerce document.

I have successfully limited the result with below properties:

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=20&page=2
/wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=745
```

However, I am trying to get a product with attribute, but it is not working:

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products?attribute=pa_brand&attribute_term=899
```

I have checked, and my attribute name `pa_brand` & term_id/tag_id `899` both are correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this will answer/help your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66546184/woocommerce-api-list-all-products-with-a-specific-attribute

Comment: I have already tried as /wp-json/wc/v3/products?attribute=pa_brand&attribute_term=899, but it didn't work.

Comment: There was some conflict with the plugin, however I have deactivated all the plugins except WooCommerce and it's working.

Comment: But the multiple attribute is not working. Suppose I have to filter data from 2 attributes like pa_brand and pa_color, how can I do that?